# Differenze di uso tra "ritornare" e "rientrare"

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, verbs, word-choice, difference

Non capisco bene quali sono le differenze di uso tra i verbi "ritornare" e "rientrare" quando hanno il senso di tornare di nuovo a un posto. Per esempio, immaginate una persona che è andata a vivere per alcuni anni all'estero ma adesso è di nuovo nella mia città, con l'intenzione di restare per un po' di tempo. Cosa dovrei dire? È ritornata a Barcellona? È rientrata a Barcellona? Posso usare ambedue i verbi? Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Come indicato dal Treccani, *rientrare*, che ha come primo significato quello di ”entrare di nuovo” in un luogo da cui si era usciti, può significare, per estensione, “tornare” in un luogo abituale (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rientrare/). Nel caso proposto nella domanda, si può dire *tornare a Barcellona* o *ritornare a Barcellona* in ogni caso e, solo nel caso in cui la persona sia di Barcellona o Barcellona sia la sua residenza abituale, *rientrare a Barcellona*.

Comment: D'accordo, posso usare "tornare", ma "ritornare" non si usa in questo contesto?

Comment: Se ho capito bene la risposta, se si tratta di una persona che è vissuta per molti anni a Barcellona e soltanto un paio d'anni all'estero, potrei anche usare "rientrare", vero?

Comment: @Charo, correggo la risposta: ho scritto “tornare” invece di “ritornare” (dicono la stessa cosa).

Comment: Perfetto, @Benedetta! E cosa ne dici del chiarimento che ho chiesto nell'altro commento?

Comment: Perfetto, @Benedetta! E cosa ne dici del chiarimento che ho chiesto nell'altro commento?

Comment: @Charo: puoi usare anche "rientrare", certamente.